# Using a $_GET variable for id in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ezsql

I would like to use a GET variable from the URL and use it in a MySQL select statement as an id, then echo the results out on the page. I was able to echo out the $_GET variable by itself, but I am not able to use it as a variable in a query.Why is the code below not working?

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/core/config.php');
include_once "shared/ez_sql_core.php";
include_once "ez_sql_mysqli.php";
$db = new ezSQL_mysqli(DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_USER,'localhost');

$client = (int)mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['client']);

$results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=" . $client.  ";");

foreach ( $results as $data ){ 
    echo $data->name; 
  }

?>
```

Comment: why you using (int)? and add $db --- ($db,$_GET['client'])

Comment: @dass because (int) is the only meaningful operator here, while mysqli_real_escape_string is useless

Comment: If you want to fetch value from the url then you can use `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I would check your database connection `ezSQL_mysqli(DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_USER,'localhost');` This line looks like total nonsense

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You're using DB_USER twice, once for the username and once for the database name, is it done on purpose ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using that ezSQL thing wrong way.

Here is how it have to be used:

```
$client = $db->escape($_GET['client']);
$results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client'");
```

However, I'd strongly recommend to get rid of this ridiculously insecure solution and use PDO instead:

```
$results = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=?");
$results->execute([$_GET['client']]);
foreach ( $results as $data ){ 
    echo $data->name; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the mysqli verison woked, but he PDO version has given me a HTTP error 500